# Setting column width for printing VBA

Tags: vba, excel

my excel spreadsheet has an exhibit number that I'd like to be printed perfectly under my right-alined right header. The code below gets it close but fails to align the header and the exhibit number. The difference gets worse when I change the scale on that table. (exhibit number formatting in Excel is not an issue) Pls help:

```
Dim i, w, colNum As Integer
Dim Exh, exh_name, slide, slide_ch As Variant

w = 100 * (10.8 * 72 - (ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftMargin + 
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightMargin)) / ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Zoom

slide = 0
slide_ch = 0
colNum = 9

For i = 1 To colNum - 1
 slide = slide + Columns(i).Width
Next

Columns(i).ColumnWidth = WorksheetFunction.Max(1, w - slide) * 
Columns(i).ColumnWidth / Columns(i).Width
```

[image]

Comment: As a side note - `Dim i, w, colNum As Integer` is only declaring `colNum` as an integer and `i` and `w` as variants. This should be written as `Dim i as Integer, w as Integer, colNum As Integer` instead. Also, could you please include a picture of the current result and your desired result? Working to position *anything* in Excel can be tedious...

Answer (score 1):

I found no computational answer to this problem. So I built my macro to add small increments to the column width I wanted to be aligned with the header. Once the process resulted in column jumping to the next page, I subtracted the last increment. The macro feels a little sluggish, but not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to store a calculation involving precise decimals in an `Integer` - an `Integer` will always round up or down, truncating any decimal places - If you need precise coordinates, declare your variables as `Long` instead, which will store digits precisely up to 15 places.

`Dim i as Long, w as Long, colNum As Long`

Comment: Thank you for looking into this @dwirony, tried changing w to long. The exhibit is still off.

Comment: What are these headers, are they pictures? Are you sure it doesn't contain white space to the left/right of it?

Comment: "Exhibit" is right-aligned and formatted as General. It is flush against the right border of the column.